# sharepoint online communication site - image sizes

Tags: sharepoint-online

SharePoint online communication site (o365) - image sizes

Need help with exact sizes to create some vector illustrations for the following SP Comms Site areas:

- Hero Cards
- Banners/page mastheads
- News/Post Page banners/mastheads

The code is responsive, but Microsoft hasn't revealed any cut off points

Can anyone offer a reference guide or sizes for my project?